# How to position the userform below the command button

Tags: vba

I have created a command button and when I click the button an `userform1` is shown and the userform has a calender control in it and it is popping at the center of screen but I want that to be positioned below the command button. Is there a way to say that position the userform1 below the button?

Well, I have given the axes size and its working on my pc but when the pixels changes it is somewhere again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the Command button in on one user form and the calendar control on another.

You do not say which version of VBA you are using.  I tested this in Excel 2003.  I know better solutions are available in, for example, VB  2010.

**Approach 1**

Do you need a second form?  You can hide a control with:

```
ControlName.Visible = False
```

and make it visible with

```
ControlName.Visible = True
```

**Approach 2**

You need some public variables in a module:

```
Public ButLeft As Integer
Public ButHeight As Integer
Public ButTop As Integer
Public Form1Left As Integer
Public Form1Top As Integer
```

Within the click event for the command button, include:

```
' This stores information about the current position of
' Form 1 relative to the active window.
With Me
  Form1Top = .Top
  Form1Left = .Left
End With
' This stores information about the current position of the
' command button relative to the useable part of Form 1.
With Me.CommandButton
  ButTop = .Top
  ButLeft = .Left
  ButLeft = .Height
End With
```

Within Form 2 include:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

  ' This positions Form 2 relative to the current position
  ' of the command button.  The "+50" is because the stored
  ' values do not allow for the width of Form1's border.
  ' Experiment to get values that look good to you. 
  With Me
    .Top = FormTop + But1Top + But1Height + 50
    .Left = FormLeft + But1Left + 50
  End With

End Sub
```

With this code, Form 2 displays under the command button no matter how the user moves Form 1.